# req.session.user is display value when console.log while log in and displays undefined while i check it in property-controller why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

I'm building a backend using Node.js, Express for session management. For whatever reason, when i login i set the user credentials to req.session.user and console.log it displays the user credentials but when in property-controller when i check it before adding property that if the user is logged in so to add the property when i console log it it displays undefined why?

This is the app.js file

```
require("dotenv").config();
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const HttpError = require("./models/http-error");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const countRoutes = require("./routes/count");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
const property = require("./routes/addproperty");
const remarks = require("./routes/remarks");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb+srv://asadnisar108:asad4291@cluster0.05d8yek.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to the database");
    app.listen(5000, () => {
      console.log("Server is running on port 5000");
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

  

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: oneDay,
      sameSite: true,
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: true,
      userId: '',
    },
  })
);

app.use("/uploads/images", express.static(path.join("uploads", "images")));

app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/home", countRoutes);
app.use("/property", property);
app.use("/remarks", remarks);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  return next(new HttpError("Could not find this route", 404));
});

module.exports = app;
```

this is the auth controller login function

```
const login = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { userId, phoneno, password } = req.body;
  let existingUser;
  
  

  try {
    existingUser = await User.findOne({ phoneno: phoneno });
    console.log(existingUser.id, 1);
  } catch (err) {
    return next(new HttpError("Logging in is failed,Please try again!", 500));
  }

  if (!existingUser) {
    return next(new HttpError("Invalid credentials, User not exit!", 401));
  }

  let isValidPassword;
  try {
    isValidPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, existingUser.password);
  } catch (err) {
    return next(new HttpError("Could not log you in, please try again", 500));
  }

  if (!isValidPassword) {
    return next(new HttpError("Invalid credentials,Please try again!", 401));
  }

  // Create a session and store user data in it
  req.session.cookie.user = existingUser;
  req.session.save();
  console.log(req.session,43);
  res.json({ message: "Login successful", userId, phoneno });

  // res.status(200).json({message: "Logged in Successfully"});
  // res.send();
};
```

this is the property-controller file create property function

```
const createproperty = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.session);
  const usersId = req.session.cookie.user;
  if (!usersId) {
    return next( new HttpError("User not logged in", 401));
  }
  
  //using sharp
  let imagePath = [];
  for (let file of req.files) {
    let sharped = await sharp(file.path)
      .resize(300, 200, {
        fit: "fill",
      })
      .toFile(file.destination + "/addproperty" + file.filename);

    console.log("sharped:::", sharped);

    imagePath.push(file.destination + "/addproperty" + file.filename);

    fs.unlinkSync(file.path);
  }

  const {
    propertypurpose,
    propertytype,
    propertysubtype,
    propertysize,
    propertysizetype,
    propertyprice,
    propertytitle,
    propertydescription,
    propertylocation,
    propertybuiltyear,
    permalink,
    propertynoofbedroom,
    propertynoofbathroom,
    propertynoofcarparking,
    images,
    propertyPrimaryDetaile,
    propertySecondaryDetaile,
    propertyServices,
    propertyEntertainment,
    propertyNearByLandmarks,
    numberoffloors,
    unitfloor,
    name,
    phonenumber,
    propertyaddeddate,
    featured,
    verified,
    userId ,
    // creator,
  } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);

  const createdReport = new Property({
    propertypurpose,
    propertytype,
    propertysubtype,
    propertysize,
    propertysizetype,
    propertyprice,
    propertytitle,
    propertydescription,
    propertylocation,
    propertybuiltyear,
    permalink,
    propertynoofbedroom,
    propertynoofbathroom,
    propertynoofcarparking,
    images: imagePath,
    propertyPrimaryDetaile,
    propertySecondaryDetaile,
    propertyServices,
    propertyEntertainment,
    propertyNearByLandmarks,
    numberoffloors,
    unitfloor,
    name,
    phonenumber,
    propertyaddeddate,
    featured,
    verified,
    // userId:req.session.user?._id || null,
  });

  let userproperty;
  try {
    console.log("signup3");
    console.log(userproperty);

    userproperty = await createdReport.save();
    console.log(userproperty);
    res.send();
    // sendWelcomeEmail(userData.phoneno, userData.name);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return next(new HttpError("Creating Property is failed. Please try again!"));
  }
  console.log(req.body, "hey");
  // res.status(201).json({ message: "Property Added" });
  res.send();
};
```

All i want is that after login where credentials are saved when i create the property the user credential show be access not displayed undefined